# Onclick to a function doesn't work

Tags: javascript

im creating an online quiz with buttons, my problem is that the onclick button isn't really doing what i hoped it would, im a beginner in javascript so i was hoping people can give me solutions or alternative suggestions to make it work;

here is my code

```
<html>
<head>
<title> </title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="qholder"> </div>
<button name="choices" onclick="CheckAnswer('A')" > <p id="choice1"> </p> </button>

<button name="choices" onclick="CheckAnswer('B')" > <p id="choice2"> </p> </button>

<button name="choices" onclick="CheckAnswer('C')" > <p id="choice3"> </p> </button>

<button name="choices" onclick="CheckAnswer('D')" > <p id="choice4"> </p> </button>

<script>

var qpos = 0;
var correctans=0;
var answer=0;


var Quiz = [
    ["What team was the first TI Champion?", "Invictus Gaming", "Team Liquid", "Natus Vincere", "Orange E-Sports", 'C'],
    ["Who was the captain of the First TI Champion Team?", "Puppey", "Artstyle", "Kuroky", "xiao8", 'B'],
    ["Where does Natus Vincere Operate?", "USA", "Moscow", "Philippines", "Ukraine", 'D'],
    ["Who played Midlane for Natus Vincere?", "Miracle", "Suma1l", "Dendi", "Maybe", 'C'],
    ["How many TI grandfinals did Team Natus Vincere played in?", "3", "2", "1", "4", '1'],
    ["Who replaced LightofHeaven after leaving Natus Vincere?", "General", "Sonneiko", "rodger", "Funn1k", 'D'],
    ["Who defeated Na'Vi in the TI3 Grand Finals?", "Team Liquid", "Cloud 8", "Evil Geniuses", "Team Alliance", 'D'],
    ["Who is the current captain of Team Na'Vi?", "Pajkatt", "Cr1t", "Sonneiko", "Fly", 'C'],
    ["Who is the owner of Na'Vi?", "Gaben", "CyborgMatt", "ODpixel", "zer0gravity", 'D'],
    ["When was Team Natus Vincere Founded?", "July 1996", "December 2009", "November 2012", "March 2017", 'B']
];

function startquiz(){   
    getQuestions(); 
};  

function getQuestions() {

        document.getElementById("qholder").innerHTML = Quiz[qpos][0];
        document.getElementById("choice1").innerHTML = Quiz[qpos][1];
        document.getElementById("choice2").innerHTML = Quiz[qpos][2];
        document.getElementById("choice3").innerHTML = Quiz[qpos][3];
        document.getElementById("choice4").innerHTML = Quiz[qpos][4];

        };  


function CheckAnswer (answer){
    if(Quiz[qpos][5] == answer) {
      correctans + 1; 
    };
  getnextQuestion();    
};


function getnextQuestion() {
    qpos + 1;
    getQuestions();
};

startquiz();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

pls help, i've been stuck for hours trying to figure it out, i used a multi dimensional array for my question, choices and answers and would like the button onclick to proceed to the next question while it checks if the clicked answer is right

Comment: `the onclick button isn't really doing what i hoped it would`.  What did you hope it would do that it's not doing now?

Comment: i hoped that when you click it; it would run the function CheckAnswer(1) with a value inside the parameters so i can compare the value to the correct answer which is my Quiz[pos][5] array but it doesnt do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
qpos + 1
```

needs to either be `qpos++` or `qpos = qpos + 1` at the very least

Comment: WOW THANK YOU SO MUCH, THIS ACTUALLY FIXED IT I KNEW THERE WASN'T ANYTHING WRONG WITH HOW I SET MY BUTTONS OMG THANK YOU THIS FIXED EVERYHING

sorry caps im so hyped right now since ive been stuck for a while

Comment: just a pro tip, you can check by either adding console logs around things (I did to see if your values were changing) or using break points in your browser's dev tool of choice.

Answer (score 0):

```
function CheckAnswer (answer){
    if(Quiz[qpos][5] == answer) {
        correctans++; 
    };
    getnextQuestion();  
};


function getnextQuestion() {
    qpos++;
    getQuestions();
};
```

Comment: fixed it with the previous post, same idea as yours thank you